# Building a search engine that searches for specific types of content?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, search-engine

I'm looking to build a search engine that returns results for specific types of content from the internet: Articles, Blogs, Videos and Podcasts. The question is what are some viable ways to go about this? I've looked into building a search engine with the likes of Solr or elastic search but this looks like a huge amount of work... I've also looked at Google Search API however this looks like it could get expensive quickly and I'm not sure if you can filter results for only specific content types?

What are some approaches to go about solving this problem? What would be needed if I built something like this from scratch?

FYI - This search engine would need to accessible from a react-native application.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't know why you feel using elasticsearch or solr is a huge amount of work.**

if we talk about elasticsearch which is a very popular open-source distributed REST-based search engine. It's very simple to build an efficient and cost-effective performant system for your use-case. elasticsearch provides [SDK in all major languages](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html) and can be deployed from one node to thousands of nodes in the production.

**EDIT: based on comment**, pleaser refers to the [filter context of elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) which can be easily used to filter the content based on content type(you need to have a field in your elasticsearch index obviously in order to filter on it) and good news is that its by default cached at elasticsearch so gives your very good performance out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've done some research and seemed like it was a lot of work to get something that only returned the specific content types I want. Perhaps I was mistaken... How would I go about filtering results with something like elastic search or solr? and generally what are steps involved in building a search engine with either of these tools? :)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I need this to be accessible from a range of application firstly a react-native application? Would I just run it on Node.js and then connect it to my react-native app?

Comment: @HarrySayers as mentioned earlier Elasticsearch is REST(JSON) based and you can easily use language clients(which I mentioned earlier) or any HTTP client to access their APIs, what you have is a very common way to build the app and its very easy to integrate elasticsearch into it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223028/discussion-between-harry-sayers-and-opster-elasticsearch-ninja).